# For a coupling there does not exist an extension.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-extensions

Let $N$, $Q$ be groups and there is group homomorphism $$\Phi: Q \to Out(N)= Aut(N)/Inn(N),$$ we called such $\Phi$ to be coupling. For every extension of $N$ by $Q$ there exist a coupling.

> What about the converse? That  is, if we have a coupling $\Phi$, does there always exist an extension of $N$ by $Q$ that induce the coupling $\Phi$?

I know converse is also true, if $N$ is abelian group. What about for non-abelian case?

Please give a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample is $N = 2.A_6 \cong {\rm SL}(2,9)$, the double cover of the alternating group $A_6$.

The automorphism group of $N$ is isomorphic to $A_6.2^2 \cong {\rm P \Gamma L}(2,9)$. The three extensions $A_6.2$ are isomorphic to $S_6$, ${\rm PGL}(2,9)$ and a group that is often denoted by $M_{10}$, the point stabilizer in the Mathieu group $M_{11}$. (Another description is that $M_{10}$ is the extension of ${\rm PSL}(2,9)$ by hte product of a diagonal and a field automorphism.)

There is no associated group with structure $2.M_{10}$ (the ATLAS of Finite Groups is a good source for this type of information).

So if we let $Q=C_2$ and $\Phi$ the homomorphism with image the outer automorphism inducing $M_{10}$, then there is no associated coupling.

Comment: How do you conclude that there are only three extensions of the group N. Can you please suggest some reference for this example?

Comment: I am talking about the three extensions $A_6.2$ that are subgroups of ${\rm Aut}(N)$.

Comment: ohky..thanks for the help. But i think i need more explanation for this could you please suggest some reference?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any easy references. This example is discussed at the top of page xxiv of the ATLAS of finite groups. There is also some discussion of the Schur Multiplier of $M_{10}$ [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362103), but it's not easy to follow!

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.